# What could be wrong with auto-defrost system in the fridge?

Tags: refrigerator

Defrost system in my Whirpool french door fridge is not working. Cold area compartment gets warm a week after full defrost with the help of hair dryer while freezer keeps working normally. I checked the termostat, the heating element, they all have continuity. The only thing left to check is the control board but I have no idea how to test whether it sends voltage to heating element or not (it's supposed to do that at its own schedule). Any ideas? Could it be something other than CB?

Comment: There could be an issue with the timing circuit on the defrost. If you could get some schematics for your model, I'd be happy to help troubleshoot that circuit.

Comment: I can't find the schematics but the control board model is AP5657149. I see lots of complains on Google about this model so you are probably right. Some people suggest turning on/off lights in the fridge 5x within 6 sec. to force defrost cycle. It's supposedly should confirm that the defrost system itself is working.